# Model with classname [App\Order] not registered as admin module. in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model, repository

I am working on someone's code and having an issue in Laravel New Model.
when I am trying to create a new Model and Page on blade view but I couldn't and having this error.

> ErrorException in Models.php line 48: Model with classname [App\Order] not registered as admin module. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\floatthat\vendor\sleeping-owl\admin\src\views_partials\menu.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\floatthat\vendor\sleeping-owl\admin\src\views_partials\menu.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\floatthat\vendor\sleeping-owl\admin\src\views_partials\menu.blade.php)

my menu file when I added new with name

```php
Admin::menu('App\Order')->icon('fa-tag');
```

```php
 <?php

    Admin::menu('App\User')->icon('fa-users');
    // Admin::menu()->label('User Floats')->icon('fa-credit-card')
    //     ->items(function () {
    //         Admin::menu('App\Deal')->icon('fa-tag');
    //         Admin::menu('App\Image')->icon('fa-image');
    //     });
    Admin::menu('App\Deal')->icon('fa-tag');
    Admin::menu('App\Order')->icon('fa-tag');
    //Admin::menu('App\Order')->label('Add new menu');
    Admin::menu('App\CompletedDeal')->label('Completed Floats')->icon('fa-            trophy');
    Admin::menu()->label('Offer Packages')->icon('fa-money')->items(function() {
    Admin::menu('App\OfferFloat')->label('Offer Floats');
    Admin::menu('App\FloatOfferFloat')->label('Packages');
    });
    Admin::menu('App\Product')->icon('fa-dropbox');
    Admin::menu('App\Category')->icon('fa-list');
    Admin::menu(config('floatthatpkg.models.urlalias'))->icon('fa-link');
    Admin::menu('App\SystemConfig')->icon('fa-gear');
    Admin::menu('SleepingOwl\AdminAuth\Entities\Administrator')->icon('fa-key');
```

I need to add that Order view and file but having an issue. In Img you can see.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that `Models.php` in included in Laravel, post the code of that class, and what version of laravel you're using

Comment: its an admin package  https://github.com/sleeping-owl/admin/blob/master/src/SleepingOwl/Admin/Models/Models.php#L48

Answer (score 1):

You have to register the new model with the SleepingOwl admin package. See [Model Configuration](http://sleeping-owl.github.io/en/Getting_Started/Model_Configuration.html) in their documentation.

```php
Admin::model(\App\Order::class);
```

Comment: in which file exactly?